# Filter a Dictionary to return a list

Tags: vb.net

I know I can do this with a for loop cause that's how i'm doing it now.  I was hoping for a more efficient way to accomplish the task.

I have a dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
or Of String, Boolean.
i want to get a list(of integer) or Of String from the dictionary where all the values are true(or false depending on what i need at the time)

and to generalize it or "black box" it, it could be any dictionary(of whatever, whatever)
and return a list(of whatever) where the value = whatever i'm looking for at the time.

string, string where value = "Closed"

in short: i want all list of all the keys who's value = some criteria

my current code:

```
    Public Function FindInDict(Of tx, ty)(thedict As Dictionary(Of tx, ty), criteria As ty) As List(Of tx)
    Dim tmpList As New List(Of tx)

    For xloop As Integer = 0 To thedict.Count - 1
        If CType(thedict(thedict.Keys(xloop)), ty).Equals(criteria) Then
            tmpList.Add(thedict.Keys(xloop))
        End If
    Next
    Return tmpList
End Function
```

Comment: I think that a For loop may be your best bet here. But I may be wrong

Comment: Also, I can do like myList.Find(criteria) or myList.FindAll(criteria), is there a dictionary equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with Linq:

```
Public Function FindInDict(Of tx, ty)(thedict As Dictionary(Of tx, ty), criteria As ty) As List(Of tx)
    Return (From kvp In thedict
            Where kvp.Value.Equals(criteria)
            Select kvp.key).ToList()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ, like so:

```
Dim tStorage As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim tKeys As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim tCriteria As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

tStorage.Add("One", "Uno")
tStorage.Add("Two", "Dos")
tStorage.Add("Three", "Tres")
tStorage.Add("Four", "Quatro")

tCriteria.Add("Dos")
tCriteria.Add("Quatro")

tKeys = (From k In tStorage.Keys Where tCriteria.Contains(tStorage(k)) Select k).ToList

For Each tKey As String In tKeys
    Console.WriteLine(tKey)
Next

Console.ReadKey()
```